# Parameters not in the credible interval interpretation in Bayesian model

Tags: r, bayesian, statistical-significance, jags, credible-interval

I create a spline model in a Bayesian framework and all the parameters that are estimating the spline (the random effects of the spline) are lying between a Credible interval of negative something to positive something (meaning that they could all be 0).

Here is an excerpt of my parameters:

```
Summary of the model:
                        mean      2.5%     97.5%  Rhat n.eff
b[52]          -0.0932960823  -1.25004   0.78165 1.001  4800
b[53]          -0.0340564823  -1.06345   0.89334 1.001  3000
b[54]           0.0373573273  -0.87171   1.10736 1.001  4400
b[55]          -0.0321806634  -1.02698   0.86092 1.002  2200
beta[1]        -0.4001445133  -1.09681   0.35688 1.004   670
beta[2]        -0.3507544649  -1.49971   0.91127 1.004   580
beta[3]        -0.0301274796  -1.30425   1.17904 1.002  2200
deviance      589.1109606139 528.73266 654.80578 1.002  1400
m[1]           -0.6235506741  -1.43866   0.18972 1.002  1900
m[2]           -0.4353551517  -0.99317   0.20707 1.004  1000
m[3]           -0.4147866288  -0.97221   0.21866 1.004  1100
m[4]           -0.4897174582  -1.05414   0.14259 1.003  1300
```

How should I interpret the model? Should I say that the model is not good at all to estimate the other parameters? Should I simply ignore these "non significant" parameters? Or should I assume that the model is badly written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP's question about splines can be generalized as a question about *model selection*, or re-instantiated in multiple regression where it's called the question of *variable selection*. In multiple regression, which of several candidate predictors should be included in the "best" model? Or for nested models more generally, which subset of parameters should be included in the "best" model? The answer to this sort of question is not brief, and is addressed by many different methods (in frequentist and Bayesian approaches).

One Bayesian approach is to incorporate an *inclusion parameter* with every parameter of interest. An inclusion parameter is discrete and takes on values of zero or one, and is a multiplier on the corresponding model parameter. Bayesian inference yields the posterior probability that the inclusion parameter is one, that is, the posterior probability of including the corresponding model parameter. It's actually a posterior probability on the joint space of all combinations of parameter inclusions, so it's a posterior probability distribution of inclusions combinations. Unfortunately in practice it can be difficult to do the computations, especially in MCMC, because the chains won't mix well, that is, won't smoothly jump across models. But you can give it a try; see Section 18.4 of [DBDA2E](https://sites.google.com/site/doingbayesiandataanalysis/) regarding variable selection in multiple linear regression for examples and caveats.

As I said, this is a huge topic, and I've only suggested one conceptual approach.